# Perl -d and modulino issue

Tags: perl, debugging, modulino

I have some scripts that I have started unit-testing using the "modulino" idea. I have encountered a problem in that when the script is called with "perl -d" the script does not run as caller() returns a true value.

I have the main body of the script wrapped in a main() and some subroutines being slowly pulled out of the main() into their own subroutines.

At the top of the script I have:

```
main(@ARGS) unless caller();
```

When called in .t tests it works as I want, not running main() so I can test the subroutines. When I call the script from CLI it works great calling main().

The problem occurs when I call it from the CLI with:

```
perl -d myscript.pl
```

At this stage caller returns a valid value (rather than undef) and main is not called.

Suggestions would be much appreciated about how to approach this one.

Comment: Good catch. I'd never consider that since I hardly ever use the perl debugger. Thanks, :)

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce this behavior.  I wrote a tiny modulino, and the debugger still works fine.  Can you post an example?

Comment: There should be `@ARGV` instead of `@ARGS`. In case someone was just copy-pasting :)

Answer (score 9):

The situation with `-d` switch is similar as with testing - your code is executed by something else, in this case the debugger.

You can either run `main` yourself by calling it in the debugger manually or you have to detect if `caller` is debugger. Something like:

```
main(@ARGS) if !caller() || (caller)[0] eq 'DB';
```

Comment: Your condition is wrong.  If `caller` is true, then the second condition never gets evaluated.  Try `unless caller and (caller)[0] ne 'DB'`.

Comment: @cjm - thanks, fixed. I turned condition to positive as it took me quite some time to figure it out.